# Convert JSON data from Request into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to scrape some data from a web page and put it into a pandas dataframe. I tried and read many things but I just cannot get what I want. And I want a dataframe with all the data in separate columns and rows. Below is my code.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

r = requests.get('http://www.starcapital.de/test/Res_Stockmarketvaluation_FundamentalKZ_Tbl.php')

a = json.loads(r.text)

res = json_normalize(a)
##print(res)

df = pd.DataFrame(res)
print(df)

##df = pd.read_json(a)
##print(df)
```

`pd.read_json(a)` doesn't seem to work in any way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://www.starcapital.de/test/Res_Stockmarketvaluation_FundamentalKZ_Tbl.php')

j = r.json()

df = pd.DataFrame([[d['v'] for d in x['c']] for x in j['rows']],
                  columns=[d['label'] for d in j['cols']])
```

Result:

```
In [217]: df
Out[217]:
                   Country  Weight  CAPE    PE    PC   PB   PS   DY  RS 26W  RS 52W  Score
0                   Russia     1.1   5.9   9.1   5.1  1.0  0.9  3.7    1.22    1.35    1.0
1                    China     1.1  12.8   7.2   4.5  0.9  0.6  4.2    1.05    1.13    2.0
2                    Italy     1.0  12.7  31.5   5.7  1.2  0.6  3.3    1.13    1.11    3.0
3                  Austria     0.2  14.3  21.7   7.3  1.1  0.7  2.5    1.10    1.15    4.0
4                   Norway     0.4  12.8  32.4   7.4  1.6  1.2  4.0    1.10    1.17    5.0
5                  Hungary     0.0  12.5  49.8   7.5  1.4  0.7  2.3    1.12    1.19    6.0
6                    Spain     1.2  11.7  24.7   7.0  1.4  1.2  3.7    1.08    1.11    7.0
7                    Czech     0.0   8.9  13.6   6.1  1.3  1.0  6.7    1.03    1.05    8.0
8                   Brazil     1.3   9.8  42.1   7.4  1.6  1.2  3.0    1.06    1.24    9.0
9                 Portugal     0.1  11.3  29.0   4.8  1.5  0.7  3.9    1.05    1.06   10.0
..                     ...     ...   ...   ...   ...  ...  ...  ...     ...     ...    ...
42        EMERGING MARKETS    13.5  14.0  16.0   8.8  1.6  1.3  2.9    1.04    1.11    NaN
43        DEVELOPED EUROPE    22.4  16.6  26.5   9.9  1.8  1.1  3.2    1.06    1.08    NaN
44         EMERGING EUROPE     1.7   8.6  10.9   5.8  1.1  0.8  3.4    1.13    1.20    NaN
45        EMERGING AMERICA     3.0  15.2  30.1   9.4  1.9  1.2  2.4    1.03    1.11    NaN
46  DEVELOPED ASIA-PACIFIC    17.7   NaN  17.7   8.8  1.3  0.9  2.5    1.03    1.09    NaN
47   EMERGING ASIA-PACIFIC     6.9  14.9  15.1   9.1  1.8  1.4  2.7    1.01    1.08    NaN
48         EMERGING AFRICA     0.8   NaN  16.5  10.6  2.0  1.4  3.8    1.06    1.12    NaN
49             MIDDLE EAST     1.3   NaN  13.7  11.8  1.5  1.8  3.9    1.06    1.10    NaN
50                    BRIC     5.9  11.8  14.6   7.4  1.4  1.2  2.7    1.06    1.16    NaN
51     OTHER EMERGING MKT.     2.5   NaN  17.7  12.9  1.8  1.5  3.1    1.16    1.20    NaN

[52 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: Justin's answer below is better IMHO. Ran into `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` with this solution while his worked like a charm.

Answer (score 57):

Or, more simply:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://www.starcapital.de/test/Res_Stockmarketvaluation_FundamentalKZ_Tbl.php')

j = r.json()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j)
```

Answer (score 6):

And one step simpler than Justin's (already helpful) response...by putting .json() at the end of the `r = requests.get` line

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://www.starcapital.de/test/Res_Stockmarketvaluation_FundamentalKZ_Tbl.php').json()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also want [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for when your data isn't exactly the way from_dict() expects.

For example:

```
data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cole Volk",
        "fitness": {"height": 130, "weight": 60},
    },
    {"name": "Mark Reg", "fitness": {"height": 130, "weight": 60}},
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Faye Raker",
        "fitness": {"height": 130, "weight": 60},
    },
]
pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=1)
    id        name  fitness.height  fitness.weight
0  1.0   Cole Volk             130              60
1  NaN    Mark Reg             130              60
2  2.0  Faye Raker             130              60
```