# How do I convert a Json from GET request into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, post, python-requests

I'm using the GoToWebinar APIs to get data from webinars.
I did everything but the only bit missing in my script is the conversion of the Json I get to a dataframe in pandas so that I can progress the analysis.

The Json file I get has the following structure (I masked the data):

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "webinars": [
      {
        "webinarKey": "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG",
        "webinarId": "BBBBBBBBBBB",
        "organizerKey": "RRRRRRRRRRRRR",
        "omid": "RRRRRRRRRRR",
        "accountKey": "WWWWWWWWWWW",
        "recurrenceKey": "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE21",
        "subject": "LEEEEEEEEEESEon",
        "description": "EEEEEEEEEEEEE",
        "times": [
          {
            "startTime": "2019-07-01T13:00:00Z",
            "endTime": "2019-07-01T13:30:00Z"
          }
        ],
        "timeZone": "America/New_York",
        "locale": "en_US",
        "status": "UPDATED",
        "approvalType": "AUTOMATIC",
        "registrationUrl": "https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/rt/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "impromptu": false,
        "isPasswordProtected": false,
        "recurrenceType": "series",
        "experienceType": "broadcast",
        "registrationSettingsKey": "DDDDDDDD"
      },
      {
        "webinarKey": "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG",
        "webinarId": "BBBBBBBBBBB",
        "organizerKey": "RRRRRRRRRRRRR",
        "omid": "RRRRRRRRRRR",
        "accountKey": "WWWWWWWWWWW",
        "recurrenceKey": "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE21",
        "subject": "LEEEEEEEEEESEon",
        "description": "EEEEEEEEEEEEE",
        "times": [
          {
            "startTime": "2019-07-01T13:00:00Z",
            "endTime": "2019-07-01T13:30:00Z"
          }
        ],
        "timeZone": "America/New_York",
        "locale": "en_US",
        "status": "UPDATED",
        "approvalType": "AUTOMATIC",
        "registrationUrl": "https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/rt/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "impromptu": false,
        "isPasswordProtected": false,
        "recurrenceType": "series",
        "experienceType": "broadcast",
        "registrationSettingsKey": "DDDDDDDD"
      },
..other webinars.....
 ]
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 10,
    "totalElements": 26,
    "totalPages": 3,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

This is my code, I basically don't know how to progress.
I tried DataFrame.from_dict, read_json and also the solution presented here: [Convert JSON data from Request into Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518864/convert-json-data-from-request-into-pandas-dataframe)

```
'''Getting the webinar lists'''
base_url = 'https://api.getgo.com/G2W/rest/v2'

##setting up paramters
param_1 = '2019-07-01T10%3A00%3A00Z'
param_2 = '2019-09-01T10%3A00%3A00Z'

##buidling the path
path = base_url + '/accounts/' + account_key + '/webinars?fromTime=' + param_1 +'&toTime=' + param_2
print(path)

headers = {'accept' : 'application/json' , 'Authorization' : access_token}

webinars_req = session.get(path, headers = headers)

webinars_json = webinars_req.json()
```

I would like a dataframe that has all the internal labels (e.g. webinarkey, webinarid etc) as columns with the correspondent value...

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: Hi, can you update the question with the required dataframe? It will be easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `requests` module

```py
import requests

webinars_req = requests.get(path, headers = headers)
df = pd.read_json(webinars_req.text, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately that doesn't work because the type returned is actually a dictionary type and not a json object. I posted my solution below in case it can be helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it!
Basically I only had to get the list from the dictionary at a webinars level and then put it in a dataframe:

```
webinars_json = webinars_req.json()

##put all webinars data in a dataframe

webinars_list = webinars_json.get('_embedded').get('webinars')
df_webinars = pd.DataFrame(webinars_list)
```

It worked nicely :-) 
Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

`js = { "_embedded": { "webinars": [ { "webinarKey": "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG", "webinarId": "BBBBBBBBBBB", "organizerKey": "RRRRRRRRRRRRR", "omid": "RRRRRRRRRRR", "accountKey": "WWWWWWWWWWW", "recurrenceKey": "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE21", "subject": "LEEEEEEEEEESEon", "description": "EEEEEEEEEEEEE", "times": [ { "startTime": "2019-07-01T13:00:00Z", "endTime": "2019-07-01T13:30:00Z" } ], "timeZone": "America/New_York", "locale": "en_US", "status": "UPDATED", "approvalType": "AUTOMATIC", "registrationUrl": "https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/rt/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "impromptu": "false", "isPasswordProtected": "false", "recurrenceType": "series", "experienceType": "broadcast", "registrationSettingsKey": "DDDDDDDD" }, { "webinarKey": "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG", "webinarId": "BBBBBBBBBBB", "organizerKey": "RRRRRRRRRRRRR", "omid": "RRRRRRRRRRR", "accountKey": "WWWWWWWWWWW", "recurrenceKey": "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE21", "subject": "LEEEEEEEEEESEon", "description": "EEEEEEEEEEEEE", "times": [ { "startTime": "2019-07-01T13:00:00Z", "endTime": "2019-07-01T13:30:00Z" } ], "timeZone": "America/New_York", "locale": "en_US", "status": "UPDATED", "approvalType": "AUTOMATIC", "registrationUrl": "https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/rt/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "impromptu": "false", "isPasswordProtected": "false", "recurrenceType": "series", "experienceType": "broadcast", "registrationSettingsKey": "DDDDDDDD" } ] } }`

```
import json 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
s = json.dumps(js) #convert dict to string 
data = json.loads(s) #load str as json 
#also look at meta arguments for json_normalize 
df = json_normalize(data=data['_embedded'], record_path=['webinars'])
```